# Call/move a function from inside an "if loop" of another function - Qt, C++

Tags: c++, qt, authentication

I am trying to implement a login page in qt and stuck in a weird problem. I want to check for 2 types of passwords. One is the regular password and the second one will be the masterpassword. When the used enters wrong password 5 times, he has to enter master password and if he also enters 3 wrong password, there will be an error on display.

I have written the code, but facing a problem which I am unable to fix. Here is my login code:

```
void FormLogin::OnLogin()
{
    QString password = passLineEdit->text();

    // Checking if username or password is empty
    if (password.isEmpty())
        {QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Warning!"), "Password field is empty!");
    } else if (password == "pass")
    {this->destroy();
    } else {
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Warning!"), QString("Wrong password!!! Only %1 attempt(s) left!").arg(4-attempt));
    attempt++;
    if (attempt == 5){
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Warning!"), QString("The device is locked due to too many failed attempts. Please enter the master password to unlock the device now."));
        connect(loginButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(OnMasterLogin()));
        return;}
        }       
}

void FormLogin::OnMasterLogin()
{

    QString mpassword = passLineEdit->text();

    // Checking if username or password is empty
    if (mpassword.isEmpty())
        {QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Warning!"), "MPassword field is empty!");
    } else if (mpassword == "masterpass")
    {this->destroy();
    } else {
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Warning!"), QString("Wrong mpassword!!! Only %1 attempt(s) left!").arg(2-master_attempt));
    master_attempt++;
    if (master_attempt == 3){
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Warning!"), QString("The device is permanently locked due to too many failed attempts. Please contact the device manufacturer."));}}

}
```

I want to call the second function only when the attempt in the first function is equal to 5. But after 5 loops, my code calls the second function but it then runs the first function and second function simultaneously. Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong? I tried to combine the function together and tried to use the second function as nested loops inside the first one, but it still calls the whole function even if I set it inside an "if loop" condition:

```
void FormLogin::OnLogin()
{
    QString password = passLineEdit->text();

    // Checking if username or password is empty
    if (password.isEmpty())
        {QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Warning!"), "Password field is empty!");
    } else if (password == "pass")
    {this->destroy();
    } else {
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Warning!"), QString("Wrong password!!! Only %1 attempt(s) left!").arg(4-attempt));
    attempt++;
    if (attempt == 5){
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Warning!"), QString("The device is locked due to too many failed attempts. Please enter the master password to unlock the device now."));
        QString mpassword = passLineEdit->text(); 
        // Checking if username or password is empty
        if (mpassword.isEmpty())
            {QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Warning!"), "MPassword field is empty!");
        } else if (mpassword == "masterpass")
            {this->destroy();
        } else {
            QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Warning!"), QString("Wrong mpassword!!! Only %1 attempt(s) left!").arg(2-master_attempt));
            master_attempt++;
            if (master_attempt == 3){
            QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Warning!"), QString("The device is permanently locked due to too many failed attempts. Please contact the device manufacturer."));}}}
        }       
}
```

The first function is called using the following code:

```
connect(loginButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(OnLogin()));
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have connected loginButton::clicked() to FormLogin::OnLogin() already. In that method, at five attempts, you *add* another connection, to FormLogin::OnMasterLogin() but you leave the original connection still in place. Use disconnect() or add logic to FormLogin::OnLogin() to bail out if currently in "master login"-mode.

Comment: Adding `disconnect(loginButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(OnLogin()))` to the first function where the `return` was worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `if (attempt < 5)` condition before calling the first function. This should prevent from entering the first fonction if the 5 attempts are reached.